# Formula to move cursor until it finds something, then copies a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Any ideas on how I can fill out my column C?

I have data that is multiple rows that represent a set (in my example, I colored each set).  I need to look in Column A, and if the entry in Column A is 3 digits long, go pick up the entry in column B.  If the entry in Column A is not 3 digits (it would then be 4 digits), then go up until you find the first entry with 3 digits, and then go across and copy the entry in column B.

The number of rows in a set is not fixed (mostly is 4, but sometimes can be 6 or even more).  There can be two rows in the set that are 3 digits, in which case, fortunately, the column B value is the same.

[image]

I have OK Power Query skills (though would need some pointers there too), but since I'm almost done with this project in Excel, I'm hoping to solve this within Excel.

Comment: You are showing the desired result, that's good. However, without a view on the current state of your sheet, I do not see how to answer your question.

Comment: ... and you need it to work within the coloured sets?  i.e. if the colour of a row is different to the last then start the logic from that point?

Comment: @skin yes, I need it to do it for each set.  (The sets are not colored, btw.  I just did that so it was clear what rows together were a set.)

Comment: @atmo - just imagine Column C being blank.  How I want it to wind up looking is how I filled out in the example.

Comment: So how would a formula determine a set of it’s not coloured?

Comment: That's what I'm hoping someone can help with.  :-).  Is there any formula that says "move up until you find something 3 characters in length", then chose the item in column B of that row?

Answer (score 1):

Look at it like this:
If the A value is between 100 & 999 then use B value from same row.  Otherwise, drag down the C value from the row above.  In C4 code the formula:

```
=If(And(A4>=100,A4<1000),B4,C3)
```

Now fill that down and that should do it.

Comment: Ooo, yes, I think I can probably work with something like that!

Comment: Similar approach to check the length instead of the number value: `=IF(LEN(A4)=3,B4,C3)`

Answer (score 0):

### Fill With Matches

**1. Normal**

```
=SCAN(0,(LEN(A3:A22)=3)*B3:B22,LAMBDA(rr,r,IF(r>0,r,rr)))
```

**2. LET**

```
=LET(code,A3:A22,account,B3:B22,
SCAN(0,(LEN(code)=3)*account,LAMBDA(rr,r,IF(r>0,r,rr))))
```

**3. First Match**

If you decide that *"There can be two rows in the set that are 3 digits, in which case, fortunately, the column B value is the same."* no longer applies:

```
=LET(code,A3:A22,account,B3:B22,
    a,(LEN(code)=3)*account,
    b,VSTACK(0,DROP(a,-1)),
SCAN(0,a*(a>0)*(b=0),LAMBDA(rr,r,IF(r>0,r,rr))))
```

[image]

**Edit**

To make it also work for strings:

```
=LET(code,A3:A22,account,B3:B22,
    a,IF(LEN(code)=3,account,""),
    b,VSTACK("",DROP(a,-1)),
SCAN("",IF((a<>"")*(b=""),a,""),LAMBDA(rr,r,IF(r="",rr,r))))
```

Comment: Thanks!  I am going to investigate this.  I've heard of lambda.  Now I have a reason and context to explore it.